# How to hide status bar and inside an Iframe

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, css

I have added an iframe to show a power point diagram on SharePoint classic page. By default it has a some tool bars and other sections in the iframe. I would like to clear all the controls and tool bars so that only the diagram appear on the  iframe. I have attempted the below on a script editor but no luck

```
  <iframe id="myframe" src="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites//PMCMInternational/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={c8700571-d499-4dc9-a623-52957080fd9f}&amp;action=embedview&amp;wdAr=1.7755102040816326&amp;Embed=1" width="350px" height="221px" frameborder="0">This is an embedded <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> presentation, powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.</iframe>


<script>
el = document.getElementById('myframe')
if (el != null) {   
    alert('id :' + el.id)
    if (el.name!=""){
        alert('name: ' + el.name)
document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument.getElementById("WACStatusBarContainer").style.display="none";
    }
    else{
        alert('frame do not have name attribute')
    }
}else{
    alert('frame do not exist')
}
</script>
```

As I understand Iframe's css cannot be directly editable can someone guide me on how to proceed?

Comment: SharePoint online? SharePoint Server? I doubt that applies to both. Viso (block chain payment system)? Do you mean Visio (diagram software)? Details matter.

Comment: Sorry I ment Visio Diagram, Its sharepoint online classic page I have updated the question

Comment: I am trying the same with Power Point to remove the status bar but its still the same

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that with javascript/jQuery, because the domains Visio runs on and your code runs on are different, for security reasons. You might want to consider using API `Application.showToolbars` to control the toolbar.

See reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/visio/visio.application?view=visio-js-1.1#showtoolbars

Comment: I have added Viso diagram in an iframe as above and used this code on a script editor function hideToolbars() {
    Visio.run(session, function(context){
        var app = context.document.application;
        app.showToolbars = false;
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            window.console.log("Toolbars Hidden");
        });
    }).catch(function(error)
    {
        window.console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
};   from the reference you have provided, but its does not seems to work. Am I missing somthing?